# What is the .idea folder?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I create a project in JetBrains WebStorm, a folder called `.idea` gets created. Is it okay if I delete it? Will it affect my project?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project.html

Comment: To easily manage all the folders/files you do not want to commit to Git, you can use the IntelliJ plugin .ignore: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495?pr=idea

Comment: but where is the `.idea/` folder supposed to be at? I am looking under ever folder my project has and it's in none of them.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

When you use the [IntelliJ IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), all the project-specific settings for the project are stored under the `.idea` folder.

> Project settings are stored with each specific project as a set of xml
> files under the .idea folder. If you specify the default project
> settings, these settings will be automatically used for each newly
> created project.

Check [this documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-and-ide-settings.html) for the IDE settings and [here is their recommendation on Source Control](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) and an example .gitignore file.

Note: If you are using git or some version control system, you might want to set this folder "ignore".
Example - for git, add this directory to `.gitignore`. This way, the application is not IDE-specific.

Comment: *"If you are using git or some version control system, you might want to set this folder "ignore". "* .. how exactly?

Comment: @Shafizadeh .gitignore should be a hidden file in the root directory of you app. Edit this text file and add "/.idea" as it's own line.

Comment: Forget about future git crashes due to the .idea folder (especially when working on the same project from different computers). Simply open your .gitignore file and add `.idea`

Comment: but where is the `.idea/` folder supposed to be at? I am looking under ever folder my project has and it's in none of them.

Comment: Note) Not only IntelliJ, but most other Jetbrain's IDEs such as Webstorm, Pycharm, etc. create `.idea` folder.

Answer (score 20):

As of year 2020, JetBrains suggests to commit the `.idea` folder.
The JetBrains IDEs (webstorm, intellij, android studio, pycharm, clion, etc.) automatically add that folder to your git repository (if there's one).
Inside the folder `.idea`, has been already created a `.gitignore`, updated by the IDE itself to avoid to commit user related settings that may contains privacy/password data.

It is safe (and usually useful) to commit the `.idea` folder.

Comment: Hi, could you please share a link to JetBrains' suggestion? I would like to explore it, see the reasons for that etc.

Comment: same here... I would also like to see this

Comment: @Lada @Itzkhan [This is the document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) that explains how to manage `.idea` over version control.

Answer (score 17):

There is no problem in deleting this. It's not only the WebStorm IDE creating this file, but also PhpStorm and all other of JetBrains' IDEs.

It is safe to delete it but if your project is from GitLab or GitHub then you will see a warning.

Comment: but where is the `.idea/` folder supposed to be at? I am looking under ever folder my project has and it's in none of them.

Comment: it's initially got hidden. but you can see it when you open this project on any editor

Comment: @CharlieParker like @MH Fuad said, you just need to do `ls -la` in the root and you will see it, even if it strangely doesn't show up in the Jetbrains project tree

Answer (score 13):

It contains your local *IntelliJ IDE* configs. I recommend adding this **folder** to your `.gitignore` file:

```
# intellij configs
.idea/
```

Comment: but where is the `.idea/` folder supposed to be at? I am looking under ever folder my project has and it's in none of them.