# What does it mean when the "out" folder in a project is highlighted in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: out folder highlighted with an orange background]

Why is the `out` folder and all its content highlighted? Does it mean I did something wrong?

Comment: This is your project after compiling. No need to worry about it. You can see the project structure after compiling in it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the function of the "out" and ".idea" folder in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362009/what-is-the-function-of-the-out-and-idea-folder-in-intellij)

Answer (score 4):

This is the [project compiler output](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.2/project-settings-and-structure.html#compiler-output) directory. The red color means that it is [excluded  directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.2/content-roots.html#folder-categories) in project. Files in excluded folders are ignored by code completion, navigation and inspection.

Answer (score 0):

This folder is created when you're compiling your project and contains compiled classes.