# Should the /out folder in an intellij project be added to gitignore?

Tags: intellij-idea, gitignore

I have observed the following different files in my intellij java project -

- .idea folder
- .out folder
- .iml file
- .src folder

Out of these files I'm thinking of adding .idea folder, .out folder, .iml file to .gitignore? Am I right? Or do these folders and files hold some significance which needs tracked by git?

Answer (score 0):

Please see how to handle files in .idea in terms of Git:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

Answer (score 0):

The .out folder can be added to .gitignore, since it is created once the project is built (when you press Run in IntelliJ).

The .iml file and the .idea folder stores information about your project. Do NOT add this to .gitignore, as it is needed when others clone your project and build it themselves.

Source/s:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44362056/14368392
- https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207097529-What-is-the-idea-folder-