# Error: Entrypoint isn't within the current project

Tags: flutter

Unable to run flutter from Android Studio not detecting flutter project its shows Error: Entry point isn't within the current project

Every time restart android studio same error message shows

[image]

Answer (score 84):

Delete the  `.idea` folder inside the root of the flutter project and restart Android Studio.

Refer to this question: [What is the .idea folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049416/what-is-the-idea-folder) and make your decision if it's safe or not to delete `.idea` folder.

Comment: This solution + `Invalidate Caches and Restart` was the key in my case

Comment: This is the perfect solution. And don't forget to Invalidate Caches and Restart the andriod studio after deleting .idea folder. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

> Click on File-> Project Structure -> Module then add root folder of
>   your project then it will detect its a flutter app and then build and
>   work

its work for me

**Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2307**

Comment: When i open Project Structure it says, "Select configuration element in the tree to edit its settings". what do i do?

Answer (score 23):

After updating from Dolphin to Android Studio Electric Eel I was getting this issue.

Below trick helped me to make my flutter project working again.

- Switch to **project mode** if not.
- **Right click on project name**.
- Select **Mark Directory as** -> **Sources Root**

[image]

Comment: This is the answer that helped me. I think it may be the most accurate now.

Answer (score 16):

**1)** make sure **flutter** and **dart sdk** paths are properly configured from

**File-> Settings..->Languages and Frameworks**
as well as **make sure Dart support is enabled** for project module from **Dart** Option
[image]

**2)** at the end select **File->Invalid caches and restart**

[image]

**3)** so after 2nd step you may get in **File->Project Structure..** option from there Select Modules then just simply add only **root folder path** of your flutter project and **repeat just above 2nd step**
for me this worked

Answer (score 6):

Syncing your project with gradle files will solve it:

[image]

Comment: The project  is not a Gradle-based project.This is flutter not android, Please check once again

Comment: I faced this same problem in my flutter project where the android part is using gradle, and it solved the issue for me.

Comment: I tried but not working.Please find the attached screen shot for more information
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZDEP.png

Comment: those solutions might be helpful : https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2307

Answer (score 5):

For me my project was missing the pubspec.yaml file, it was deleted by mistake , instead of warning about the missing file , I got this error

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If your ios, android, or lib folders are missing, it typically means there is something wrong with your project structure.

To fix it, delete the .idea folder in the root of your project and then restart Android Studio. If you're using a Mac, you can display the hidden .idea folder by [pressing Command+Shift+Dot in Finder](https://setapp.com/how-to/show-hidden-files-on-mac#:%7E:text=See%20hidden%20files%20on%20Mac%20via%20Finder&text=In%20Finder%2C%20open%20up%20your,2%20to%20hide%20them%20again!).

The .idea folder will be automatically regenerated and everything should be back where it belongs.

See [this post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2307#issuecomment-627768384) for the original solution.

Comment: I was able to run my project thanks to this solution.
I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

You can sync the files with Gradle, within the File menu.

Else You can re-include the files/project root folder inside the File Menu.

File -> Project Structure -> Module

And then add the root folder of the project(with + icon), then it will detect that it's a flutter app again, and then build and work again.

Answer (score 4):

Try delete .idea folder inside project folder and Invalidate & Restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

This problem happened to me

I solved it this way

Go to the Android Studio track

I have this way

```
C:\Users\mustafamaxL\.AndroidStudio4.0\system
```

Remove folder (caches)

Then, start Android Studio again

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because I renamed the Flutter Project at VS Code and when I opened at Android Studio, the old name was coming from .idea files.

To solve, I closed Android Studio and I deleted the .idea directory.

Comment: Yes, rename the project on VSCode can be a nightmare kkkkk. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The .idea folder will also be deleted on Linux. When Andriod Studio opens, click terminal at the bottom in Android Studio. Then type `remove -r .idea/` in the terminal and press enter. After deleting, close and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Click Content Root Close Icon and Remove Android Folder.

Fix it to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have created 2 folders inside lib's folder for my *pages* and *widgets*. 
Getting the main.dart file back to the **lib folder** will do the trick
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today and tried other solutions here but it wasn't worked at all.

In my case I **deleted** three folders that is `android`, `ios`, and `.idea` from project directory, then restarted **android studio** and finally I gave this command in Android Studio's Terminal.`flutter create .` to create appropriate directories (i.e., android & ios).

**Now it is working fine.**

**Note:** Before deleting the **android / ios** directory please make a backup of these directories only if you previously gave native code in android / ios directory.

Hope this solution will helpful if others will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to **update the Gradle version.** Or change the minimum android SDK version.

Here is worked for me:

#### Update Gradle / minSdkVersion version

1. Reopen the project but at the directory `user/StudioProjects/yourFlutterApp/android`.
   After it is opened it will load some packages (see right bottom), which will take some time.
2. It will ask you to update the Gradle version (right-left corner) or go under `File>Project` `Structure Project` you can set a higher Gradle version and under `Modules` variables of your build
3. Now you can sync your project with Gradle files

After configuration, you might need to restart your project with `File>Invalid Caches/Restart...`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently in Android Studio Electric Eel.

I've done all of the suggested solutions above, but nothing works.

Turns out the project is not detected as a Flutter project. So what I do to resolve this issue is to remove gradle-related files from the root folder:

1. `build.gradle`
2. `gradlew`
3. `gradlew.bat`
4. `gradle/`

Comment: Hi @Erick, This one also not working

Comment: It worked by Marking Project Directory as Resources Root

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the following issue in Android Studio

```
Error: Entrypoint isn't within the current project
```

Here is the solution for my case,
Open File-> Project structure then select your project in module tab and also set dart sdk in dependencies tab.

[image]

Another Screenshot is here:
[image]

Hopefully, you've resolve your issue by these steps.

Answer (score -2):

For none of the provided solutions worked. What I had to do is save my work and then go `File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings...`

This will reconfigure SDK paths (Android, Dart, Flutter). It may sound like a hustle but it works and it's not that difficult to configure the settings again with the current version of Android Studio.
Using: *Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch*