# I can't click main.dart key and can't run

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I open it my project but I can't run it.. I didn't do anything. How can I resolve this problem???[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weEr9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the drop down icon on side of "main.dart" with flutter icon error and go to "Edit Configurations...", see if shows any error name or code. If there is an error or a code, send it here, maybe this will help more

Comment: Thanks for your help and there's Error ' Entrypoint isn't within the current project

Comment: There is a link to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000043/error-entrypoint-isnt-within-the-current-project#:~:text=If%20your%20ios%2C%20android%2C%20or,and%20then%20restart%20Android%20Studio.) on stackover flow. About the same topic
Hope will help!

Answer (score 0):

click on **File** >> click on **Settings** >> search by **sdk** >> click on **Dart**(inside Languages & Frameworks) >> check **Enable Dart support for the project** >> select Dart SDK path >> check **Enable Dart support for the following modules** >>  click on **Apply**

You should see the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLogt.jpg) If you have any confusion.

Then I think you get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this warning 'Entrypoint is not a dart file' after saving work done is by following this.

- Go To File in Android Studio
- Menu at the top Manage
- IDE Settings Restore Default Settings
- Restart the App
- Download necessary Plugins back to your App and you can continue using it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  you  should missing (MyApp) in main.dart don't applyed !.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Steps

In Window

```
Go To File -> Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Flutter -> Select Flutter SDk Path
```

In Mac

```
Click on apple icon-> Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Flutter -> Select Flutter SDk Path
```

Screen shot =>

[image]