# Where do IntelliJ IDEA store "Use project settings" settings

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make Maven run faster by "work offline" & "skip tests" inside IntelliJ IDEA 2019.

Online guides tell me to go into "Run > Run/Debug Configurations" and change appropriately.

All of them are grayed out, except for a checked "Use project settings". I figured I would like to change the "project settings" because its not something I want to use on all projects.

But I cannot find where do I change the project settings.

I've tried "File>Project Structure" and I can't find anything similar. Googling yield nothing of interest either. Can someone point me to the right direction?

[Picture showing the "Use project settings" but not where they are stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTF8U.png)

Comment: What do you mean by run faster? cause once build there is no download at all. So going offline will not really change a thing. Skipping tests might be a bad idea. The question is how long does you build take and how long do you tests take?

Comment: Hi, I'm currently taking 30 seconds over to compile a nearly empty Maven project, with 0 tests, on an SSD. That is quite long compared to...an empty non-Maven project which is done under 10 seconds.

Comment: Which maven version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I'm not exactly sure since I reformatted my computer yesterday, but I've fully updated IntelliJ IDEA prior to reformatting. It should be 3.6.1, or whatever the latest version supplied up to yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: @Ersoy and @Mafick explained on the actual file location, which also addresses this question. Here's where to find them in IntelliJ GUI.

After some fiddling around after I gave up, found them in

"File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment".

[Where to find the project-specific build settings in IntelliJ IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTov5.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you import a project into your IntelliJ IDE an `.idea` folder and a `.iml` file will be created. I think the information will be in there.

Here a link to another question which also catch up this theme: [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049416/what-is-the-idea-folder)