# What is the fileTemplates folder in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just found these files hidden into my .idea folder in an IntelliJ project.
How am I supposed to use them?

What are they for???

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049416/what-is-the-idea-folder

Comment: No actually I was asking about the highlighted files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are your **project specific** [file and code templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-file-and-code-templates.html).

[image: project templates]

Answer (score 2):

Those files are the templates for when you create a new file,

For example, if you create a new class in `IntelliJ`, it will follow that template.
You can customize these templates (by going to Settings/Preferences and Editor | File and Code Templates) to save time writing code!